# PHP looped output of mySQL table is missing one row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, foreach

Summary of problem: I have a mysql table with some data, I use some phpcode to display the data to an html page, to setup JavaScript variables before a page loads. The loop seems to work fine with one exception, the first row of the table gets dropped or doesnt show. I cant figure out why, is there a small bit of logic Im missing?

I have a mySQL table here:
http://gyazo.com/ac75247b1a3f11f59721f03ff9c80d08

and some php code to display it here:

```
//...

$sql        = "SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_CALCULATOR." WHERE calculation_status = 'A'";
$result     = mysql_query($sql);
$row        = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_rows   = mysql_num_rows($result);

if(count($num_rows) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $calculator_data[] = $row;
    }
}else{
    // Send Notication to admin Calculator not set
}

//...

<?php

if(!empty($calculator_data)){
    foreach($calculator_data as $k => $v ){

        if($v['name_value'] == 'perWinPriceMatrix'){

            $per_win_matrinx = explode(",", $v['calculation_values'] );
            $per_win_matrinx_final = array_chunk($per_win_matrinx, 5, true);

            foreach($per_win_matrinx_final as $key => $values ){
                  $var[$key] =  $key.':['.implode(',',$values).']';

            }
            ?> var <?php echo $v['name_value'] ;?> = <?php echo "{".implode(",", $var)."}";?>;<?php echo "\n";
        }else{
            ?> var <?php echo $v['name_value'] ;?> = [<?php echo $v['calculation_values'] ;?>];<?php echo "\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

this is the output:

```
 var tax_bronze2 = [30,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_bronze3 = [30,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_bronze4 = [25,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_bronze5 = [25,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_silver1 = [35,30,30,5,0];
 var tax_silver2 = [30,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_silver3 = [30,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_silver4 = [30,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_silver5 = [30,20,20,5,0];
 var tax_gold1 = [70,50,30,10,0];
 var tax_gold2 = [60,40,20,8,0];
 var tax_gold3 = [60,40,20,8,0];
 var tax_gold4 = [60,40,20,8,0];
 var tax_gold5 = [60,40,20,8,0];
 var tax_platinum1 = [100,75,40,10,0];
 var tax_platinum2 = [80,65,40,10,0];
 var tax_platinum3 = [80,65,40,10,0];
 var tax_platinum4 = [80,65,40,10,0];
 var tax_platinum5 = [80,65,40,10,0];
 var tax_diamond1 = [0,0,0,0,0];
 var tax_diamond2 = [120,85,50,20,0];
 var tax_diamond3 = [120,85,50,20,0];
 var tax_diamond4 = [120,85,50,20,0];
 var tax_diamond5 = [120,85,50,20,0];
 var perWinPriceMatrix = {0:[4,4,4,4.5,4.75],1:[5,5.3,5.7,6.2,6.2],2:[7.8,8.6,9.7,10.8,11.8],3:[13,15,17,18,18],4:[19,21,25,30,40]};
 var price_matrix = [19,20,20,20,32,24,24,24,24,42,46,51,53,56,60,60,65,74,79,140,186,214,242,298];
 var provisionalPrice = [60,80,9.25,13,1.3,0.75];
```

**question: Why is output missing a row?**

Comment: Delete this line $row        = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: Someone should point this out, so it might as well be me: mysql_ functions are deprcated becuause they are insecure. Switch to mysqli_ or PDO (This is not to say your particular query is unsafe, since it as no variables in it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delete `$row        = mysql_fetch_array($result);` this line fetch row #1

Comment: That perfectly fixed it. Thank you.